# Show text or button for specific time in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a simple project in Python GUI. I want to show text or button for a specific time interval, let's say from t = 5 to t = 10 seconds. How do I do that?
I am using `tkinter` library in python

Comment: Use `root.after(5*1000, widget.destroy)` to destroy the widget after 5 seconds after the code has ran.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this following:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
def new_button():
    this_b = tk.Label(root, text='This is label will be destroyed after 5 seconds')
    this_b.pack()
    this_b.after(5000, this_b.destroy)
button = tk.Button(root, text='Show label', command=new_button)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Instead of `root.after(5000, lambda: this_b.destroy())` use `root.after(5000, this_b.destroy)`

Comment: Also adding `command=new_button` wouldn't be a bad idea :D. And `button.pack()`

Comment: @thelizzard damn it! Thanks!